# Is "has or will read" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunction-reduction

I just wrote [*[he] **has or will read** [some text]*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9866?m=10575492#10575492) in an ELL chat room. But looking at it (or more accurately, listening to my "inner voice" trying to "read it aloud"), I find it bothers me a lot.

A quick check on Google Books finds a claimed 432 written instances of [**has or will read**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has%20or%20will%20read%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and 910 instances of [**has read or will read**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has%20or%20will%20read%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22has%20read%20or%20will%20read%22&oq=%22has%20read%20or%20will%20read%22&gs_l=serp.3...7072.7822.0.8685.5.5.0.0.0.1.122.399.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..5.0.0.PSQtIUBqVnc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.jOYpRJj4zMA.O&fp=c0b43071fc779672&biw=1369&bih=911), which suggests a significant minority of writers don't have a problem with the fact that the two different *read*'s don't sound the same.

When I check the same construction with other verbs that *don't* have the same written form for past participle and present tense, it seems people nearly always include *both* (e.g. [has worked or will work](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has%20or%20will%20read%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22has%20worked%20or%20will%20work%22&oq=%22has%20worked%20or%20will%20work%22&gs_l=serp.3...4219.5978.11.6232.7.7.0.0.0.0.88.396.7.7.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..91.0.0.5_7Si-_NSPo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.jOYpRJj4zMA.O&fp=c0b43071fc779672&biw=1369&bih=911):1230, [has or will work](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has%20or%20will%20read%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22has%20or%20will%20work%22&oq=%22has%20or%20will%20work%22&gs_l=serp.3...154385.156837.10.157102.10.10.0.0.0.0.73.589.10.10.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..84.0.0.P0CM9Da2-gE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.jOYpRJj4zMA.O&fp=c0b43071fc779672&biw=1369&bih=911):8; [has arrived or will arrive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has%20or%20will%20read%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22has%20arrived%20or%20will%20arrive%22&oq=%22has%20arrived%20or%20will%20arrive%22&gs_l=serp.3...3682.5257.9.5526.8.8.0.0.0.0.80.442.8.8.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..74.0.0.wZbicyv_-Sc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.jOYpRJj4zMA.O&fp=c0b43071fc779672&biw=1369&bih=911):357, [has or will arrive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has%20or%20will%20read%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22has%20or%20will%20arrive%22&oq=%22has%20or%20will%20arrive%22&gs_l=serp.3...13203.15499.8.15793.10.10.0.0.0.0.160.769.8j2.10.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..66.0.0.GYar2GJNiaU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.jOYpRJj4zMA.O&fp=c0b43071fc779672&biw=1369&bih=911):7).

I'm not usually a big fan of "grammatical rules", but it seems to me there "ought" to be a rule that you shouldn't delete one instance of the verb unless it's "the same" as the one you're keeping. And it also seems to me that since language is primarily *spoken*, "the same" ought to mean "sounds the same when spoken", not "looks the same when written".

Can anyone who knows more than me about formal rules of grammar settle this one?

---

As an aside, offhand I can't think of any verb where the past participle and present tense sound the same but are written differently (maybe there aren't any), but would deletion be okay in *that* case?

Comment: Regarding your aside: how about "come"?

Comment: @Philippe: I did actually check that one - as with *read*, usage is about 2:1 in favour of deletion ([has or will come](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has+or+will+come%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):19K; [has come or will come](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has+come+or+will+come%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):10K). But in that case both verb forms *look **and** sound* the same. I wondered if there was one that sounds the same but is written differently.

Comment: I think your instinct is right, buthe "rule" is pragmatic, not grammatical: the Adamantine Law that Whatever can be misunderstood will be. When you're writing you don't get a chance to correct misunderstandings, so you have to take the extra effort to forestall them by avoiding ambiguity. --Which is one reason why the written language has so many "rules" and conventions which are disregarded in speech.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well the original "suspect" usage was addressed to *you*, and I certainly never worried about the possibility that you might not understand what I meant (though I will admit that part of my reason for asking the question here was that I was a bit concerned you might have thought *"Crumbs! How ignorant is **this** guy!"* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, I didn't even notice. But after months on ELL I've sort of trained myself not to see things like that unless specifically invited to.

Comment: Where are the commas that would have disambiguated and saved everyone's brains from frying? :)

Comment: @Kris: The presence or absence of commas in *has [verbed] or will verb* is entirely arbitrary, as is the presence or absence of a *pause in speech*, which it represents. With or without, there's only one possible interpretation, so there's no "disambiguation" involved here.

Comment: I asked a similar question (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/) and learned that this is called _non-parallel ellipsis_. Fowler states bluntly that a sentence such as _'No state has or can adopt' is (however common) an elementary blunder_. But reading around a bit on the topic it appears that some types of non-parallel ellipsis are more acceptable to readers than other. Your sentence is an interesting variation due to the identical spelling of infinitive and past participle, but I am usually brought to a dead halt when reading such constructions and avoid them myself.

Comment: @Shoe: Good stuff. Maybe you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Your aside made me think that it should really even be possible to make a sort of garden-pathish, antanaclatic non-parallel ellipsis, and one finally dawned on me (though it only works if spoken in a non-rhotic accent): **“Surely someone has or will sort him out!”**   (To be read as: “Surely has sought him out or will sort him out!”)

Comment: @Janus: Good one! But I'd be pretty sure even if we accept "non-parallel ellipsis" as "sorta valid", no-one would accept eliding one of two completely different verbs that just happen to be homophones. Food for thought, though!

Comment: to address the offhand remark at the end, consider **run**. *Those who have or will run in Boston marathon...* also sounds awkward, so I don't think that the appropriateness of ellipsis is based on sound. the verbs have to be of the same inflectional category.

Comment: @jlovegren: I'd already checked **come** before Phillipe's first comment. Because "both" verbs *sound* the same, I don't mind it at all - and 2/3rds of tens of thousands of written instances take that position with **come**. There aren't so many for **run**, but the preference for deletion ([have or will run](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have+or+will+run%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)) is overwhelming - 1510 as against only 52 for [have run or will run](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have+run+or+will+run%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers interesting.

Comment: @jlovegren: I cannot deny that I actually asked this question more because it was "interesting" than because I seriously expected a meaningful answer to the matter of whether or not the usage is "grammatical". But I've learned that it can be called *non-parallel ellipsis*, and I really like Janus's ***antanaclatic** non-parallel ellipsis* (okay, so I had to look up *antanaclatic* - but I really liked the overall expression once I'd got past that bit! :)

Comment: Those  1020 written instances have now shrunken to six. According to Google Books, the "has read or will read" have the upperhand with [28 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has+read+or+will+read%22&tbm=bks&ei=WE6NXMXNJMy4kwWIqa64Bw&start=20&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjF2d3FsofhAhVM3KQKHYiUC3cQ8tMDCHE&biw=1322&bih=647&dpr=1.1)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That's funny. Before looking at your comment, I checked out my first two GB links in the question, scrolled to the ***5th*** page of results on each, and updated my text with whatever "guesstimate" count GB had settled down to. Then I followed ***your*** link, which for me goes immediately to the ***3rd*** page of results, with estimated total 910 (same as I'd gotten with ***my*** search). The important thing is the *ratio* (consistently about 2:1 for me), but the way these numbers bounce around is certainly a bit baffling, to say the least.

Comment: The two _read_'s are different words, so 'has or will read' is as incorrect as 'has or will peruse' or 'has or will perused'.  'He will and will be a rat.' 'He soon and then turned left.'

Answer (score 12):

The relevant grammatical rules involved here are

1. The Perfect auxiliary *have* must be followed by the **past participle** form of the next verb.
2. Modal auxiliary verbs like *will* must be  followed by the **infinitive** form of the next verb.
3. Conjunction Reduction optionally deletes the first of two **identical** verbs following auxiliaries.

The question is what counts as "identical" for conjunction reduction.
And the answer is that "identical" means "**identical in sound**". Nobody would ever **say** this sentence, for precisely the reasons described in the answers and comments here. That is, this isn't a question about English; this is about English spelling and reading, which is technology, not linguistics.

The problem with this sentence is that it **looks** like it's OK, but it doesn't **sound** like it.
Take a verb like *sing, sang, sung*, with different infinitive (*sing*) and past participle (*sung*) forms.
Then both

- **He has or will sing that song*
- **He has or will sung that song*

are ungrammatical, no matter which form is used.

And that's why

- **He has or will read that book*

is ungrammatical. It could only happen in writing; it's a cheat, like a sight rhyme. It really should be

- *He has red or will reed that book*
  (spelled funnetikly)

because words pronounced differently can't do conjunction reduction.
And spelling doesn't count.

- **No English grammar rule has anything to do with spelling or punctuation.**

If you try verbs with identical infinitive and past participle forms,  like the set of
monosyllabic final-*t* verbs like *set, set, set; cut, cut, cut*; or *put, put, put*:

- *He has or will **set** the plan in motion.*
- *He has or will **cut** them some slack.*
- *He has or will **put** it on display in the main gallery.*

These sound perfectly grammatical (if needlessly complex), to me. This despite the facts that

- the *set, cut*, or *put* following *will* must be an infinitive,

but

- the *set, cut,* or *put* following *has* must be a past participle.

The abstract grammatical category of the deleted verb seems to be irrelevant -- as long as they **sound** the same, they're identical. And as long as **that's** the case, you can delete the first one.

Comment: Just thought of a differently-weird example: _He has or will lead the band this year._

Answer (score 10):

I must say I couldn't even understand what "has or will read" even *meant* for a minute or so. I had to skip the phrase itself and read further into the context to begin to understand what you were talking about.

My answer, therefore, is that I am not merely uncomfortable with the deletion, I find it incomprehensible. "Has or will read" for me is simply unacceptable.

For what it's worth, here is something which might shed some light (or at least some interesting color) on the matter. Neurophysiologists have found that if you have two friends named Gandalf, the wave pattern generated in your brain is consistently the same for each one, and not at all the same as the other, even though the words sound the same to the ear and look the same to the eye. In other words, "read" and "read" are very much different words, their visual appearance notwithstanding.

Comment: Poles apart indeed! StoneyB (to whom the original was addressed) didn't even *notice* the "awkwardness" at the time, but to you it's so bad it actually prevented you from parsing the words at first. Admittedly, he had the benefit of more context, but even so... And I suppose I must fall somewhere in the "temperate zone" between those two poles, given that I *wrote* it without any qualms, but only had misgivings after I'd clicked *Post Comment*, and tried to read back my own text using my "inner voice".

Comment: People differ in what they notice when they read. They react to things like spelling failures (_read, reed, rede_ /rid/; _read, red_ /rɛd/; _lead, lede_ /lid/; _lead, led 'lɛd/; _dead, head, bread,_ etc) with quite a lot of different strategies. Some hear the sounds; others don't. For the record, I do, and since (a) Conjunction Reduction requires exact identity, and (b) /rid/ and /rɛd/ are not identical, I would star that particular sentence.

Comment: @John: When I read [Riddley Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddley_Walker) I found the eye dialect/futuristic spelling/vocabulary quite strange at first, but unlike [Finnegans Wake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnegans_Wake) (which I just got fed up with and abandoned halfway through), I became quite fascinated by Hoban's "could-have-been-real" language after a couple of chapters. That was decades ago, but I only recently watched [The Clan of the Cave Bear](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090848/) (1985), which also has some pretty interesting "pseudo-language". I think I "adapt" easily.

Answer (score 5):

I just realized that a question I answered a while ago was about the same issue ([How to agree verb with has and will in same sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275037/how-to-agree-verb-with-has-and-will-in-same-sentence?lq=1)). The sentence in that question used the format "[has never and will never](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has%20never%20and%20will%20never%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)."

I would be inclined to say that this structure is grammatical, based on the evidence in your post that it is actually used.

I don't think there can be a general rule that "you shouldn't delete one instance of the verb unless it's 'the same' as the one you're keeping" because that would falsely suggest sentences like the following are ungrammatical:

> I have never read that book, and I never will (read it).

Answer (score 3):

I greatly prefer "has read or will read" because I think someone reading this aloud could do so without skipping a beat.  On the other hand, "has or will read" requires the reader unexpectedly to select a pronunciation; and presents a Hobson's choice because both pronunciations are incorrect for one of the verb tenses.

May I be so reckless as to suggest using the heretical parenthetical?  E.g.: "Tommy has (or will) read the assignment."

Comment: I puzzled over the parenthetical suggestion for a bit, Paul, and eventually decided that it is unable to solve the problem. What it does it set "read" as linked with "has," and then "will" must follow suit, which it can't. No? Wrong am I, Skywalker?

Comment: What about a similar case where the two parallel words are pronounced the same ... "has or will come"?

Comment: It was over 5 years ago when I upvoted this answer. But looking at it again now I can't imagine why I did that, so I've made a "non-edit" just so I could reverse my vote. Because quite frankly I can't see how the "heretical parenthetical" makes *any difference at all* as regards the matter under consideration. (Which I ***still*** find interesting, even though I know there's no real "Answer" to be found! :)