# How to agree verb with has and will in same sentence?

Tags: verb-agreement, agreement

The sentence is-

*The management has never and will never close the door to negotiations.*

Textbooks says **closed** should be use instead of **close**.

I am confused as it sounds strange to ears. 
Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Has never closed and will never close.

Comment: A brief look with the google finds that the verb form is attracted to the nearer auxiliary.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely ungrammatical to say "*The management has never and will never closed the door to negotiations." The auxiliary "will" cannot be followed by a past participle; it has to be followed by an infinitive.

It is grammatical to use both forms explicitly, as in "has never closed and will never close."

A [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has%20never%20and%20will%20never%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) reveals that people do also use forms with ellipsis such as "has never and will never close." Some might hesitate to use this structure since the explicit verb "close" doesn't have the same form as the implied verb (closed), but such mismatches can also bee seen in other elliptical sentences, such as "The management has never **closed** the door to negotiations, and it never will (**close** them)."