# I will or will be?

Tags: grammar

*I will and look forward to ...ing*
or
*I will be and look forward to ...ing ...*

which one is correct? The latter one grammatically sounds right for me but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Similar: [Is “has or will read” grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121037)

Comment: The first is ungrammatical (assuming 'I will' isn't a fragment addressing a previous question) and the second is probably unacceptable because of the nature of the deletion.

Comment: Informally (e.g. in a text), you could probably get away with the first; however, the second is grammatically correct, i.e. *I will be, and look forward to being, [sth.]*

Comment: @Dog Lover The form ...ing doesn't indicate being, which would be shown in full, but a general participle.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, I see what you mean. I thought it was elision (of "be") on the OP's part.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Minor note: the first isn't necessarily ungrammatical. Suppose the question was: "Will you be there". In that case, "I will" is a perfectly valid response.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, ISN'T. My apologies, I thought you said assuming "I will is a fragment".

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct form is  as follows:

I **am looking** forward to seeing you.

**am looking** is present continuous and is used now because the looking forward is something you are feeling NOW (and a little before now and after now until you see the person).

Comment: The question is about parallelism, not appropriate verb-form per se.